# How to prove that the interpolant is supported in the Minkowski sum?

Tags: optimal-transport

In Villani's book, *Topics in Optimal Transportation*, Lemma 6.3 is claimed without proof.

> Lemma 6.3 (The interpolant is supported in the Minkowski sum). Let $\mu=\rho_0$, $\nu=\rho_1$ be the uniform probability measures carried by the compact sets $X$ and $Y$. Then, for all $t\in[0,1]$, the interpolant $\rho_t=[\mu,\nu]_t$ has its support included in the Minkowski combination $(1-t)X+tY$.

Is there anyone who could tell me how to prove that?

Comment: This assumes Wasserstein-$2$ distance, right? I think it doesn't hold with Wasserstein-$1$.

Comment: @dirich1337 Thank you for comments. It is not relative to any Wasserstein distances. The interpolant is defined as $[\mu,\nu]_t:=[(1-t)\textrm{Id}+t\nabla \varphi]\sharp\mu$, where $\varphi$ is the Brenier map such that $\nabla\varphi\sharp\mu=\nu$.